# How can we bring multiple low-quality posts from a single user up for review without prejudice?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, voting

The standard guidance for voters on Stack Overflow is, "vote on the content, not the user". This dates back to 2008, [when Jeff first realized it was probably a good idea to audit votes for signs of abuse](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/):

> If you irritate another user, they might be having a bad day and decide to take it out on you by methodically going through and downvoting every post you've made.

[...]

> Still, it's unacceptable behavior, and I've been getting several reports of this sort of revenge downvoting now, enough that we needed to take action to combat it.

This leaves us with a problem however...

### What should we do when a single user has posted a steady stream of poor content?

I am talking about users who post a steady stream of low-quality content *over a long period of time*, and these posts have in one way or another avoided getting negative feedback.

Granted any single person's contribution like this is seen as negligible, but if every `1` rep user starts doing it because it is tolerated that becomes a big issue in high volume tags very quickly and it encourages new users to those types of questions are ok.

If a given user's posts are being seen and voted on *as they are created*, then the quality-control systems will kick in before they are able to accumulate a large backlog of poor-quality questions: they'll be warned, rate-limited, and ultimately banned from posting anything more.

...But when this *doesn't* happen, we're left with a user who might have a long history of poor posts over time that stack up, while never having been warned, guided, or rate-limited. Getting them into the automatic system might require voting on multiple posts... especially if all their content is low quality and off-topic, and yet, this is discouraged by individuals and groups.

**So what should a conscientious member of Stack Overflow do, when encountering such a user?**

> We need a way to submit content for review with the creating of the
> content being anonymous somehow, so people can not be accused of
> malicious moderation.

Comment: [Comments archived](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/124446/discussion-on-question-by-jarrod-roberson-how-can-we-bring-multiple-low-quality) after extensive re-write of this question.

Comment: Are you talking about question, answers, or posts in general?

Comment: Feedback, help that user to become better. There is noone who will ignore feedback that is constructive, even if they can't implement it 100% to your satisfaction. Writing good posts that actually hold up to very high standards takes time. Many people either criticize very abstractly and/or expect the user to implement very hard to implement stuff from 0 to 100.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful - sorry but experience ( [not just mine](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive) ) show that any comments on down votes or close votes are too many times met with vitriol. Better to just leave anonymous well enough alone. Those that care do not need hand holding, those that do not care do not deserve your time showing you care. And it can and is just passively ignored most of the time. Comments as a general solution are an ineffective waste of time.

Comment: Pointing to the help section isn't feedback btw.. It's abstract abstract feedback. The help section is written generally and sometimes ambiguous and hard to implement in a given question. This may be because the question itself is borderline and doesn't really belong on SO, but the help section isn't very clear on most topics.

Comment: *There is noone who will ignore feedback that is constructive* @HopefullyHelpful - Unfortunately, that's not true. Just today someone (who's since deleted the question) was asking why all of their OS-related questions were getting down voted but even after being told they needed to provide code, be more specific, info in their comments needed to be in the question, etc. they insisted that it was all because they were OS questions. They didn't want feedback, they wanted to be told they were right.

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding the situation.  "Low-quality content [that] avoided getting negative feedback."  Then give it some negative feedback specific to the content, not the user.  "A long history of poor posts, while never having been warned, guided, or rate-limited."  Provide that warning and guidance, specific to the content, not the user.  If it's such that they should have been rate-limited but haven't, then that's a fault with the rate limiting system, and we can discuss it further.  But the rate limiting system needs something done by us to know which user to target.

Comment: you can't. The moment you bring it up to someone else, you're the bad person for targeting a user.

Answer (score 48):

You answer the question yourself: **vote on the content.** If the content is poor, then *it doesn't matter* if the same user wrote it or not. If the posts are good, *it doesn't matter if other posts by the same author are not*.

The problem you're running into is that you're looking past the content, past your ability to influence how these posts are scored by voting on them, and setting as your goal a specific outcome **for the user who wrote them.** You've decided up-front that someone needs to be banned or warned, and now you're looking for a means to that end...

**...Please don't do that.** It is impossible for you to be objective once you've made that decision, and your bias will spill over into both your actions and those of others whom you might influence.

Of course... that's easy to say. Once you find yourself in that position, it's very, very hard to walk back from it. So here's my advice, when you find that you've already developed a bias toward an individual:

1. **Recuse yourself.** Close their profile, and don't think about it any more. If you come across their posts as you peruse the site, you can treat them like any other - there's a reason the name of the author is at the *end* of the post, after all. But once you've lost objectivity, walk away.
2. **Ask someone else to have a look.** If you simply *cannot* walk away in good conscience, then pass it off to someone else. This could be a friend or colleague, someone else you know from the site, or simply a moderator summoned by a flag on one of the user's posts. Your friend may ignore you, and the moderator may disagree that there's a problem and dismiss your flag... *That's ok!* Remember, you're not objective here anymore; you need that sanity-check. Once you've passed the matter on to someone else, walk away and trust that they'll make the right decision.
3. **Be patient.** It pains me that there isn't more transparency into these systems, but... One reason why someone might've been posting low-quality content over a very long time is that *they've already been heavily rate-limited for doing so!* If the system limits you to one question a week, it's gonna take a while for you to build up a *history* of badness. Heck, for all you know, the last question they asked may have been the only question they'll be *allowed* to ask for the next 6 months. While you're fuming and fretting, they're doing the same... Trust that the system is actually there, working behind the scenes, and don't try to force it into action more quickly than it needs to.

#### See also: [Can there be legitimate serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260840/can-there-be-legitimate-serial-downvoting/260843#260843)

Comment: I really do not like that this answer assumes that I ( or anyone else ) inherently is incapable of objective decision making. I get the human condition, but to tell me that I can not possibly ever objectively judge individual content on its own merits just because the same person created it is unfair and subjective in its own right.

Comment: I already tried #2 via SOCVR and get shouted down about *targeting users* is a no no, and that is by definition **asking for others to review**, and simply by *asking others to review*, it is targeting, catch 22. # 3 is not a solution because these people have already fallen through the cracks in a way that they will never be dealt with passively, that has already happened and the system does not address that loophole. So the answer is #1 *Nothing*. Got it.

Comment: You most certainly can judge content on its merits, @Jarrod. But at the point where you've looked past the content and are focusing on how best to take down the author, this becomes unlikely. A question for you: of the posts you've raised in SOCVR, how many have been upvoted? How many exemplary questions have you brought to the attention of others? What would you say the ratio is, of those you've invited others to damn vs. those where you've encouraged praise?

Comment: @Jarrod you ran into our room guidelines which are a bit more strict (for various reasons) than the guidelines detailed by Shog9 in this answer. The room owners had a discussion about this and I would like to clarify our stance on this. As far as Shog9's guidance goes, go for it, ask others to review all of a user's contributions. Just please keep it out of the SOCVR. There are other rooms that will allow this, or you could make your own room for that purpose, but we do not like it, nor the negative attention it brings to the room.

Comment: @TinyGiant I disagree. If this is the policy and the reasoning for it, you shouldn't ask others to review the content of a particular user unless you're offering praise. Once you mention the user in particular, you bias everyone you're asking to review it, assuming they trust you. Ask for reviews of *posts*. Don't mention that they're all from the same user.

Comment: **How many exemplary questions have you brought to the attention of others? What would you say the ratio is, of those you've invited others to damn vs. those where you've encouraged praise?** <- This. There is already enough stick (as opposed to carrot) built into the system, gathering a group to wield the sticks is perhaps counterproductive.

Comment: @TravisJ I doubt so... if there were as much as stick as you allude to, we wouldn't have our quality problems. On the other hand, there's a hell of a carrot, where you can come with a problem, doesn't matter how vague, and people will jump in to solve it.

Comment: There's a great temptation, @Braiam, to look at the size of the problems we have to solve here and declare as a result that no effort to address them can possibly too extreme. However, this ignores the *scope* of the problem. Rare indeed is the user who can single-handedly cause significant damage or disruption to the site; the problem is almost entirely composed of thousands of individual users each creating one or two small problems. "Wielding a big stick", then, can be as counter-productive as trying to kill a cloud of mosquitoes with a 12lb maul...

Comment: But that doesn't mean that we can't try.... I mean I'm swinging a 12lb maul, it's cool! I feel good while swinging it.

Comment: SO does not have a problem with question and answers getting enough upvotes, this is strawman argument at best and disenginouse if you are trying to say I do not promote good behavior in content creation. I got one word that says how much I promote `B4Y`.

Comment: @Shog9 - what form of gas is the preferred chemical to combat the swarm?

Comment: That's not what I'm saying, @Jarrod. I'm saying - for the third time - that there is a bias inherent in a reviewer who sets out with a goal other than that of evaluating each post on its own merit. I've seen it in myself, and I've seen it in others, and the question I posed to you is meant to encourage self-reflection. As for the gas... See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216683/what-happens-to-new-users

Comment: And for the 3rd time; my goal is stated as **explicitly as possible** to assume for the sake of argument that there is no other reason other than to judge the content objectively on its own merit one at a time. I do not need any swami/guru reflection, clouding the question. Assuming that someone is looking at content one at a time and it is all falling through the cracks crap content on its own merit, there is nothing you can do about it so the only answer is #1. Do Nothing.

Comment: If your only goal is to judge content objectively, then this is a non-issue @Jarrod. You don't need any special protocols. Read a post, vote up or down, and move on. You can do this up to 40 times a day, which should be sufficient for anyone's needs and sanity.

Comment: You can review a single users contributions **objectively** and judge each question they asked on their own merits. This is completely and 100% possible, but not allowed. That is the problem that prompted me to ask this question, and I do not believe it is about *When is serial down voteing justified*, it is about promoting **reviews of individual content that just happen to be by the same person.**

Comment: @Jarrod, I've said everything I could possibly say about this topic *in abstract* - you either don't believe me, or want to talk about something else. So what else could it be? You have some beef with the rules in the SOCVR, but you don't want to talk about that so we won't. The other elephant in this room is a list of 60-some authors with multiple posts downvoted by you - often in a *very* short period of time - and which the system has invalidated your votes to.  If you wanna talk about *that* we can.

Comment: Allowing the review of content based solely on the author would be a very stark departure from the design of Stack Overflow (to note: you may be actioning the content, but the source of your review queue was a single user). Perhaps you should see how the community at large feels with regards to that topic, but I would warn you that asking such a question will result in a very negative reception. Furthermore, opening the gate to reviewing based on author is like opening Pandora's Box here. While some users may review honorably, others may not even review at all and go straight to robo-dv'ing.

Comment: @Shog9 - i  agree the subject is now beating a dead horse. Not harm no foul as far as I am concerned, I just wanted to bring it up to see if attitudes had changed, the voting shows it there is a big divide on the subject. Apathy continues to be the rule of the day. You do a great job, most of the other elected mods do as well; you are all more out numbered than those of use that do try and moderate the content to the best of our abilities. I just wanted to see if the community can help where it can, it does not seem to have the will do act.

Comment: @jpmc26 That has nothing to do with the room guidelines, but everything to do with shog's guidelines detailed here, The SOCVR explicitly disallows such behaviour.

Comment: @TinyGiant I think I ended up wording my prior message poorly. I'm glad the room forbids it. What I'm saying is that, going by Shog's post, SO is explicitly against it. So it shouldn't be done in *any* room, or on the site in general, nor outside the site. I think I'm agreeing with you, but just saying that the behavior isn't appropriate any of the other places you suggested, either.

Comment: @jpmc I figured that #2 included chat rooms.

Comment: There does seem to be a contradiction here. We are advised to vote on the content. But then the moderation ignores the content and moderates on the user.

Answer (score 16):

Quoting a paragraph from pre-Shog-edit:

> You can not effectively deal with the same number of questions from a single user as if they were asked by multiple users regardless of the quality of the content. **That by default effectively makes the single users content less low-quality.**

(Emphasis mine)

No, that is a logical fallacy:

1. If P then Q
2. Not P
3. Therefore not Q

This is not logical; Q can be true without P being true. Just because the site meters or prevents your ability to moderate multiple posts by an individual user, that doesn't mean the site thinks that those posts are good or high quality. It just means that you can't moderate the posts that way. So to answer your bold question before Shog edited it:

**No, low-quality content is not considered good or better simply *because* it is posted by a single user.**

It can still be moderated by the community, just not unilaterally by *you*.

Low-quality content is low-quality regardless of whether it's five bad posts by one user or by five separate users. The issue here is that there is currently no way for the system to determine if your actions toward this single user are legitimate or illegitimate, so it disallows user-targeting more or less altogether.

If you want to be able to moderate a user, run for a moderator position in the next election; they can and do moderate users.

Comment: The problem is, certain rules prohibit explicitly [cv-pls]ing such posts to other users. That's where the snake bites its tail.

Comment: @Olaf This Q&A is not about the SOCVR, it's about moderating users in general.

Comment: @TylerH: It was not me bringing in that room! But then, how else would you inform other users about such LQ postings? Especially if they are some time in the past for infrequent posters.

Comment: Jarrod, if you're reading this, this is why I hoped you would change your title.  This answer is answering the question you technically asked, while in no way discussing the actual problem you're interested in, namely, how the community can respond to users posting large amounts of low quality content when the question ban fails to handle the task.

Comment: @Olaf this question is not about informing other users of said content, it is about moderating the user.

Comment: @Olaf You misunderstand. Your initial comment under my answer is not relevant; we are talking about moderating individual users on the site at large; we are not talking about one specific method used in one specific place for moderating posts on the site.

Comment: That brings back my idea of a LQ-user queue. Adding a user should have high demands, but it might help mods detect such users.

Comment: @Olaf Such a feature, if ever designed and implemented, would surely be moderator-only. There is too much potential for misuse.

Comment: @Servy - I understand your point about the title, I want the title for a specific reason, it is drawing more eyeballs and more discussion because it is getting people to read it that would not read your ( or the other proposed titles ).

Comment: @TylerH - I have no interest in moderating users, I never claimed to want to do that, I have an interest in moderating content regardless of who posts it.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson It's unfortunately that you'd choose having a clickbait title to get more views at the cost of actually having a productive discussion about the issue at hand, making the (already low) odds of any useful resolution that much lower.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Right, but by filtering the content down to a single user intentionally and then acting on that content, you're targeting a specific user. So your question is somewhat missing the target I think. What it seems you really want is for the system to allow for you to perform moderation actions on a single user's content without detecting it as voting fraud or other illegitimate actions... but that's not what this question has asked.

Comment: Would raising a custom flag describing a pattern be appropriate? If mods would respond to that, including it as a suggestion might help.

Comment: @Olaf: _"how else would you inform other users about such LQ postings"_ -- you don't. And there's no need. If a single user really is responsible for a significant amount of LQ content, they are naturally more likely to gain notice by the community at large. And if that doesn't work, you can custom-flag one of their posts with a detailed comment about the problem. Even if we assume that the SOCVR room should be a focus here, "informing users" really implies using the room to mount a coordinate attack (e.g. posts are divided up one or two per reviewer). We should avoid corrosive stuff like that

Answer (score 1):

If there is an egregious moderation issue, quality-related or otherwise, that you cannot effectively deal with as a user: Flag for moderator attention.  Explain what's happening in the custom input field.

It is worth noting that

> a user who [has] a long history of poor posts, while never having been warned, guided, or rate-limited

is *extremely unlikely* and would indicate a flaw in the rate-limiting logic (and other areas) more than anything.  This is already taken care of 99% of the time.

Answer (score -12):

If we're talking about 1 rep users, then you need to create a way for them to ask for more detail in questions. A large part of why low reputation users ask duplicate questions and bad questions in general is that they can't comment to ask for more help. Often times the questions protected on StackOverflow just don't receive answers that are detailed enough to help beginners. Another thing that happens a lot is that beginners don't know enough to understand what they're actually asking when they're forced to re-ask a question because there's no way for them to get involved in an old question. That's why you get so many new users who ask cancerous questions; there's no way for them to learn without asking them.

Take all of my poor questions for example. At the time I asked them I thought there were all good and fair questions. Then I learned more about programming and realized why some of them are bad. I haven't deleted a few of them because I'm under the impression that you're not supposed to delete your bad questions here. I won't delete or modify some of my 0 point questions because I've learned too much for them.

In a lot of cases questions on StackOverflow that the community has chosen as great just don't contain enough detail to be considered good documentation for people who don't know what's happening. If there isn't a method to get more information from a well received question for people with less than 50 reputation then what are they supposed to do to get the information they need?

It's also really hard to get to 50 reputation on a Stack Exchange website to ask for clarification on a question using comments if you're new to the topic. I know that Stack Overflow isn't for beginners, but beginners are using the site in droves.

Comment: "A large part of why low reputation users ask duplicate questions and bad questions in general is that they..." don't even try to search their questions.

Comment: A 1 reputation user *can* comment on their own post though.

Comment: @Braiam They can only comment on their own post. If they find a question that already addresses their concern in a way they don't understand then, the only reasonable action they can take is to ask a duplicate question to get another explanation because they can't ask for clarification on the question they find.

Comment: @TravisJ look at my other comment

Comment: In my experience it's a bigger ask to expect users to know how to format a question for Stack Overflow than it is to expect them to know the right thing to ask about a basic or common topic. If a question needs help because it's just not meeting our requirements (e.g. it has thanks or a greeting, links to a jsfiddle demo instead of a stack snippet), I'm much more forgiving. If someone asks "I got a null reference error, how can I fix it", well, then they clearly didn't search or put forward minimal effort in trying to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: posting requirments dumps from class is the reason they ask dupes they do not try and understand existing questions even if they do search first. thus every quesiton they ask is low quality, too localized and needs to be negative feedback to let the system do its work.

Comment: [Is it okay to ask a new question about an answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284298/is-it-okay-to-ask-a-new-question-about-an-answer) (Spoiler alert: Yes, it's fine, just explain clearly what you do and don't understand.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell how is a new member supposed to find that?