# Should we refrain completely from close-voting by user?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I am an active editor, up/down voter, close voter and delete voter. My usual method to find posts that deserve editing (or down/close votes) is by text searches of common trigger-phrases that are usually the hallmark of a post that might need attention.

Occasionally I will find a user that is asking many questions that do not match our guidelines, and in those cases I will sometimes edit several questions, comment a few times, and [downvote only once](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260840/can-there-be-legitimate-serial-downvoting?s=47|0.0000).

However I had a case recently where a relatively new user was asking a lot of questions that probably could not be salvaged according to the general guidelines. Briefly they were either unclear (a lot of chatty and stream-of-consciousness writing), requests for off-topic resources, chameleon questions with a large number of updates, queries that were too broad, and so forth. It was clear they were putting in a lot of effort (they were trying hard to solve their problems) but they did not seem to have read the guidelines (my edits were not well received and my chat requests were not replied to).

I thus voted to close several of their questions. Some of these already had a handful of close votes but the inclusion of code in each case had helped them escape closure for a few days. They replied later in frustration, telling me that they had been question-banned as a result. I suspect they may have been teetering on the edge, having asked a large number of O/T questions in a couple of days, and a few closures pushed them over (one was a shopping-list question and so was also heavily DVed).

I am now wondering whether I did the right thing. I have searched here about close-voting by user, and asked in [SO CVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), and not come up with a definitive answer. I have found that organising CV by user in chat-rooms is discouraged, since this would seem to outside observers to be invoking a mob (I agree with this). I have also noticed that [revenge close-voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210254) is heavily frowned upon as well (see Shog9's comment, I agree with that too).

However, none of these guidelines apply in this case. I *think* what I did is OK, since I don't have a magic hammer close vote, and thus four other people need to independently agree with my assessment in order for the close to be successful. I believe this is what makes this issue materially different from serial down-voting, which has no such check and balance.

Nevertheless, I would like to ask to see if I should have been more careful. Since this question does not seem to have been asked before, I think it would be of interest to voters generally.

### Reaching out to user

In the interim, whilst this question gathers responses over the next few days, I have reached out to the user and offered to help improve their questions.

### Suggested duplicate

It has been suggested that my question [is answered here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335419/how-can-we-bring-multiple-low-quality-posts-from-a-single-user-up-for-review-wit). However, I don't think that post covers what I believe may be the crux of the issue.

My observation is that casting close votes requires four other people to make the same assessment, and that the odds of those other people having viewed the same user's profile are essentially zero. Thus, I am asking whether we should treat close-voting by user as different to up/down voting by user, because the first one has checks against bias and the second one does not.

Comment: You shouldn't go looking at a users posts to take action on, just focus on the ones you come across naturally instead.

Comment: ^ that, so much that.  Really the only reason to go check their other content is to see if the are a sock puppet/voting ring member/spammer.

Comment: Thanks @Joe. However, just for the purposes of exploring this theme a little bit, would you say that the check and balance of needing other CVs means that we can treat serial close by user as different to serial up/down voting?

Comment: That's a useful related post @Nathan, thanks. The answer from Shog9 says "ask someone else to have a look" (in order to remain impartial) - given that CVs need five to actually close, am I meeting that condition?

Comment: Another option as to your edits/comments not being well received and any "retaliation" is you could flag and point out the user is repeatedly making poor contributions - this also doubles as a neutral party reviewing it (as well as one that can see deleted posts and comments). In most cases the user will run themselves into some post ban anyway but if they're having a bit of a rocky start then maybe a mod message before that will give them a nudge in the right direction. Since that'd leave your name out of it - if they fancy retaliating - well - we're use to it ;-)

Comment: Thank you @Jon. I don't mind a user complaining at me, as long as it's not too unpleasant - I get why some people do not like their posts being edited at all, and they did not roll back my changes. To be fair, I think this user would have headed to an eventual post ban anyway, but I am the unlucky sod who helped to trigger it.

Comment: As far as I can gather from your question, you did *not* close-vote by user. You close-voted a crap question completely in isolation, then close-voted another question completely in isolation, and another, and another, every single one of them close-worthy *by itself* regardless of the author, which just so happened to all be posted by the same user.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: yes, I think so, though the reason people may disagree with that (and the reason why serial up/down voting is different) is that bias may persist from one assessment to another. I guess I am asking whether having four other people agree with me in each case is good enough (two people above might disagree). That's what I'd like to get to the heart of.

Comment: If you have the motivation to put this level of conscientious effort into moderation, you are a better person than I.

Comment: This is pretty orthogonal, but I believe said user also came in a chatroom I frequently roam, and they were completely unreceptive of any advice or improvement I tried to teach them. The conversation starts from [their demand for help](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36689019#36689019), and they further gave clear indication that they did not care at all about learning how to ask better questions.

Comment: @JoeW I disagree. When consulting a profile, it just so happens that I see 7 questions that are close worthy. You suggest that I should not act on the questions I see, by naturally consulting the site? Unless you imply that reading a user's profile is not "natural use of the site"?

Comment: @Félix, thanks, though I wish I had not read `and halfner is keep working to fix the syntax of my old threads / kinda .. weird and cute of him`. Sigh. The gulf between people who care about this site and people who do not is widening.

Comment: @halfer yeah, I kinda internally badly reacted to that too, but decided those two battles were not to be fought in parallel... sry, I did not think about that before posting.

Comment: @Félix: no worries, I am wearing my Kevlar today! `;-)`

Comment: Thanks @JimG for the dup suggestion. I've read that, but I don't think it deals with the issue I am trying to poke at - whether the need for five CVs is sufficient to remove the problem of subconscious bias, which would in turn make the rules about CV-by-user materially different from DV-by-user. Does it mention this on that Q, and I've just missed it?

Comment: As you say, you are searching by question then that's fine. So, my suggestion is that a "system counter" should flag or list users who "collect" multiple failing posts. Then a decision can be made by 4 moderators as to the action : contact, discussion or ban. This makes it a system control and takes any revenge action out ... Oh well my 5 pence worth and I'm relatively new here!

Comment: @SolarMike: the automation part of the ban lifts a lot of work from the shoulders of mods, and they are busy already, so I don't know if that would fly. However, we could do something similar to your idea that we do with serial up/down voting - it gets reversed automatically. But, my thesis is that the additional votes required give us a lot of anti-bias protection already.

Comment: Agreed with @JörgWMittag in the fact that if you "closed voted by user," that would suggest you went and closed a question and thought to yourself "Man this guy can't write questions at all. I'll just close all the questions he writes" whether they deserved to be closed or not. It sounds like you vetted each question respectively.

Comment: Yes @aug, I certainly tried to give each question a fair go. One or two were alright, and I gave one an upvote for the purposes of general encouragement. So, I do think it's possible.

Comment: In the absence of any opposing answers, I have accepted the top answer below, and would assert that it seems to represent community opinion presently. I encourage any other views being posted over the long term.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To be honest, I cannot see anything wrong with the actions you took. You wrote that you tried communicating with the user several times without success, and that's really all one should do before using the moderator tools available, as helping the user improve will help both Stack Overflow (better content) as well as the user (answers instead of CV's /DV's).

One should also ensure that one isn't biased against the user, and evaluate every question on its own.

I disagree with the users that commented below this question, saying that you shouldn't go after the user, and only act upon randomly stumbling over one of these questions. Would you really only clean up a pile of poop that you found in your house without looking for the source?

The reasons for me not to include the SOCVR in the closing process are that a) it's frowned upon, and b) even if it wasn't, it still would look like a witch-hunt.

Long story short, I think you did a great job, and I hope you keep your moderation efforts up. Let's hope that they learn something from this.

Comment: Thanks Seth. Yep, I'd edited a few of their posts into shape (one was subsequently updated into a chameleon question unfortunately), and I think I'd given the user +1 at some point too, for exposure on a Q that was pretty good. Let's see if we can get some views from Nathan and Joe to argue for the other side - it may be that there is not a settled view on this, and we'd have to form one.

Comment: Maybe we could have a way to send a small guideline about 'how to make questions' instead of the long text in the help.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto: Yeah, good luck coming up with something short enough to read that covers everything.

Comment: Metaphor used to justify going after user doesn't work, because SO is more of like a huge city rather than a house.

Comment: If SO is a city @user694733, then volunteer editors and voters are janitors who're willing to sweep the road. But if one of us sees a persistent litter lout, should we not try to change their behaviour?

Comment: "Would you really only clean up a pile of poop that you found in your house without looking for the source?" Best. Metaphor. Ever.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto The first law of UX: users don't read. The users that do read are the ones who care, and they don't care about the amount of text as long as it's not a wall. There is only so much that you can try to do for those who are wilfully ignorant, and that time is often better (and more productively) invested in helping those who engage.

Comment: @BoltClock: "Do some research first. Ensure your question is clear, self-contained, and would make sense to others. Code is helpful, if it applies. Be prepared for constructive criticism." What'd I leave out?

Comment: @Cody Gray: tl;dr

Comment: *One should also ensure that one isn't biased against the user, and evaluate every question on its own* this has been [emphatically stated that that is impossible for anyone to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335442/177800) by the powers that be. You are wasting your time and energy on something they do not perceive as a problem.

Comment: Thanks again Seth. I have accepted this answer for now, and added a comment under the post to encourage any more answers over the long term

Answer (score 14):

Based on the content of your question, it's hard for me to see that you could have done much more for this user. It's unfortunate they got themselves question-banned, but it was *they* who got themselves question-banned. You didn't do that. You were just there when it happened, trying to keep it from happening.

Re:

> Should we refrain completely from close-voting by user?

I can't contort myself into answering yes to that, *especially* if you've tried repeatedly to help that user improve their question quality beforehand. I think we can all agree that *intentionally* seeking out a user's questions with the goal of finding ones you can justify close-voting is uncool. But from the question, that isn't what you did; you were actively seeking questions that needed close-voting, *generally*, and unfortunately, this user's questions fit that description and kept cropping up.

You can lead a horse to water. You cannot make him drink...unless you want to intubate the horse, which is invasive, messy, and has the potential to backfire spectacularly. :-)

Comment: Alright, thanks for this. You've got me thinking of all sorts of ways of making that horse drink now. Maybe a really long straw and a small water pump?