# How and where can I report the user who permanently close my questions?

Tags: support, abuse

Recently one of the users on SO community started reviewing, closing and mark my questions for dispute (these questions are forbidden to answer) in my opinion without any reason.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75533882/2725435) is the latest example. I would like to report that user to SO moderators.. Of course I raise a flags "It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse". but it doesn't change anything. He still do the same.

Comment: *If* that question did contain any harassment, it's already been handled, as I see none in it; making it difficult to further comment on the problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting here. The question links to off-site videos, and since they seem to be essential to the question, it means that the question lacks an MCVE.

Comment: I have proposed a simple solution - convert your videos to GIF, and then they can be embedded, using the standard CDN. This rule is applied to everyone even-handedly.

Comment: "Of course I raise a flags 'It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse.'" Wait, you flagged *the question* as harassment, bigotry, or abuse?

Comment: Looking at your ["recent" questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2725435/bart%c5%82omiej-sema%c5%84czyk?tab=questions) 4 are closed; 2 as duplicates (by 2 different users) and 2 as needing debugging; 4 other users are involved in those close votes. I'm really not seeing a pattern here at a quick look.

Comment: You appear to have commented on the question that there is no reason to close it, which is mystifying - the reason for closure is explained very clearly, both here and there.

Comment: It is the reason in your opinion. I didnt have to attach videos, but I did it. Even without it, the question is clear, fully explained and easy to reproduce.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348135/should-we-refrain-completely-from-close-voting-by-user

Comment: Ok, I am closing that question. Next time I ask on meta without any example link to related question attached. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk you can try that, but people will find it anyway :) Your questions are still linked in your user CP so usually it is not too hard to figure out which one you are talking about. Heck, there are Sherlocks in meta that manage to figure out which post you are talking about when it isn't even your own based on only a description.

Comment: Are you sure the word "permanently" is the one you wanted to use? Did you mean "constantly" or "continuously"?

Comment: Video/gifs bad. Text good. Don't use images for what can be given via text, use text.

Answer (score 22):

You report such a user by flagging any post with a custom flag reason by selecting "in need of moderator's attention". But... are you sure the user is targeting you? What evidence have you got that the user is incorrectly using their curation privileges?

It would be abuse if a user voted to close your questions with invalid reasons out of spite or revenge, e.g. a user thinks you downvoted their post and they go through your profile and vote to close your questions with random reasons, or a user saw that you voted to close one of their questions and they want to take revenge on you. This would be an abuse of close vote privilege and something that mods should handle.

> I raise a flags "It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse"

You did not raise such a flag. I checked. But even if you did, this would be wrong. This type of comment flag informs mods about a comment that is an obvious breach of our code of conduct. This could be a racial slur, rude remarks towards a person or group of people, or obscene content. Voting to close a question is none of these.

Instead of focusing on being a victim of harassment, which you are unlikely to be, you should rethink your questions and address the potential close reason. Questions need at least three people to agree before it gets closed. So if one person uses their vote incorrectly, it's no big deal. But if your question ends up closed anyway, then you should address the reason for the closure and submit it for review. Don't jump to conclusions that someone is out there to do you harm. Everyone with the close vote privilege is encouraged to use it when appropriate to improve the site. Assume that the user voting to close is acting in the site's best interest before assuming that they are acting for malicious reasons.

Comment: What can I do to stop receiving downvotes? Why it is good to have opened question that only receives bad response? I want to have it deleted. Whon can I report it to make it deleted? I write it one more time. I want to stop receiving downvotes started by one user who abuse me constantly...

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk From what I can tell, you should be able to delete [the question yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions).

Comment: The OP can't delete questions that have upvoted answers, @Gimby .

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk To stop receiving downvotes, edit the question and improve it. Downvotes mean that people do not find the post useful. You need to make it more useful for the community. Do not delete and repost. This is an abuse of the system and mods will tell you to stop.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk - "I want to have it deleted." - Once you submit a question and receive an answer, as the author of the question, you no longer have the ability to delete your own question.

Answer (score 14):

### Intro

Although there is (or used to be) an ethic of not complaining about a specific user on *Meta*, I personally don't mind it - here I am, merely an avatar sitting behind an image of a sleepy cat. And the peer moderation privileges we get *are* quite powerful, so I think it is right and proper in a community that they are seen to be used fairly.

I think I became aware of your user account when I saw some misspellings from you (particularly words containing apostrophes). I vaguely recall asking you to install an English spelling checker, partly because you ask a lot of questions, and volunteer editors don't need prolific writers giving them more work. There is no sense here that perfect English is demanded - as long as you make a reasonable effort, all is good.

### Recommendations

And I wonder if that is the problem - not only are you *not* making an effort, but you're going out of your way to avoid helping. A spell-checker is so fundamental for prolific posters that there is no excuse for not installing one. Indeed, perhaps you are adding misspellings wilfully for "stylistic" reasons - there are a few others who do that, and their material is corrected too.

In a similar fashion, if your post is identified as needing a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then I recommend just supplying one. In this case, linking to videos on an external website is regarded as brittle, and that easily qualifies as needing closure, regardless of who the author is, and regardless of their rep level. For this question, you can convert the videos to animated GIFs, and then they can be included in the question directly. (As I indicated in the comments, I will cast a reopen vote if you take this simple action).

I think I have helped close some of your questions previously, though after a quick scan earlier, I could not find one. Notwithstanding, the community view is that cautious [close-votes by user is OK](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348135/should-we-refrain-completely-from-close-voting-by-user) in a way that up/down voting is not. The main justification is that close-voting requires two other independent voters to agree, and so if the initial vote was completely spurious, the closure would not succeed. I can assure you that I have not ever cast a close vote on your material where I would not have voted in the same way for another user.

(Your title indicates that you believe closure to be permanent, but this is not so - all you need to do is to repair the reason given for the closure, and ask for the question to be reopened).

### Quality

We had a short exchange a couple of days ago in which you explained that you didn't care for writing your posts with care, and that you are here to just get answers - in other words, quality be damned. I understand that view exists on Stack Overflow, though I confess I am surprised you have acquired the rep points that you have while also being of that opinion. It goes against the grain of everything we stand for here - if everyone acted only in their own interests then we'd have no community curation, no quality standards, and Stack Overflow would already have collapsed under the weight of useless, low-quality, low-effort questions.

Put another way, the reason why you come to Stack Overflow is because of its curation-level quality. So you can perhaps see why you have had a poor reception on meta: you are happy to avail yourself of a quality resource, but you don't mind that your own work detracts from that quality. You still have plenty of scope to change direction though - the minor adjustments I have asked for are completely trivial to make.

### Summary

It is not the first time that here on Meta we've seen a very high rep user being surprised by the standards that core editors and curators prefer. I acknowledge also that if you've not experienced these rules previously it can be rather a surprise (whether one thinks of this as good or poor luck is perhaps a bit of a philosophical question).

Where it helps I remain happy to work with you to improve the quality of your questions.

Comment: I have *lots* of excuses for not installing/using a spelling checker, including the fact that it's annoying and often wrong. Otherwise, a fantastic answer, and I agree with every word of it.

Comment: Yes, I also never install spelling checker. There always need to be someone for to check grammar and fix it. Also there are a millions of posts to correct. Enjoy for everyone who spend their time to make SO very perfect in every single post;)

Comment: @Bartłomiej: Cody has the advantage that their spelling is nigh-on perfect. Yours, on the other hand, is wilfully poor, and you appear to be both amused and cavalier about generating work for volunteers. That is the problem I am trying to address with you. It's not just your spelling - it's your attitude.

Comment: @Bartłomiej: if you were here in good faith, you would have committed to improving the quality of your contributions. Let us be clear: you are making an effort to make a mess, and not out of a genuine sense that your time is precious. The community wishes to explain to you that you'll have a better experience here if you can exhibit some kindness and thoughtfulness. I remain confident that you have the personal capacity to improve your behaviour.