# How can I remove an answered question which is receiving a lot of downvotes?

Tags: support, specific-question, downvotes, asking-questions, vote-to-delete

I have recently posted two questions: one on SO and one on Meta. One of the users started to abuse me and I received a lot of downvotes. I deleted my meta question, but it was undeleted and still receives a lot of downvotes. How can I stop it?

Comment: There are several things being asked here. Regarding the abuse, if you are receiving abuse, please flag the post or comment as rude/abusive (or use a moderator flag if you need to explain more detail). The rest of the asks here (and even the abuse topic) are probably duplicates.

Comment: You don't. Questions aren't just for you, they are for many people, and just because a *question* was poorly received doesn't mean that the answers are. Deleting the question deletes the helpful answer(s), and we don't (should not) delete helpful content.

Comment: Ok, so lets leave removing or closing the question. What can I do to stop receiving downvotes? Because the same happens here.

Comment: *"What can I do to stop receiving downvotes?"* Improve your questions. Write content that the userbase will receive well.

Comment: @TylerH How can I use moderator flag?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk You click the flag option and then select "flag for moderator attention". Do _not_ use it solely to complain about someone closing your question, however; it is for serious matters regarding someone violating site rules, etc. that require more information/context than one of the prescribed flag options provides.

Comment: Note that *if* you do raise a flag, as Dharman states in the [answer to your other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423343) you need to provide evidence of **targetted** and **malicious** behaviour. You have failed to demonstrate that in both this question and your prior one, which is likely part of the reason why they are being poorly received; they come across as a rant from someone who perceives downvotes as targetting the individual, not rating the content.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I received a lot of negative reviews"*? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [What is the meta effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C77.3542)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I am not fluent in english. Sorry for that. I mean downvotes rather, not reviews.

Comment: FYI: closing a question means temporarily putting it in a state where others cannot add answers until the question's author addresses the closure reason. Closing doesn't mean that the topic is solved or no longer applicable to the asker. Deleting is not the same as closing.

Comment: Ok, so how can I improve current question to stop receiving downvotes? There is no way. If you believe I can do sth please tell me. If reviewers believe it is kind of `stupid` question why it is not closed? Leaving it open for downvoting is fair for the author?

Comment: Downvotes and close votes are *not* the same thing, @BartłomiejSemańczyk . They mean different things. Just because a question is receiving downvotes doesn't mean that it should be closed, as it might still be on topic.

Comment: We do not close stupid questions. That's not one of the available reasons..

Comment: If you can't see any way to improve it then just do nothing. Why are you bothered by downvotes? Just ignore it. This is just score for other people to see, not for you to do something about it.

Comment: Also downvotes on Meta might simply mean disagreement. See: [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: I understand the difference. I am asking how to stop receiving downvotes... if I cannot close and delete question. Ok, so I leave it to the others to see my downvotes...‍♂️

Comment: Closure doesn't stop voting either, @BartłomiejSemańczyk .

Comment: You do not need to do anything. Downvotes don't necessarily mean that you should do something. If you think you can do something, do it, but you are not obliged to do anything.

Answer (score 16):

> One of the users started abuse me…

This is a serious claim, and it's one that moderators take seriously, but you're making the accusation without evidence *and* without basis (I checked). I see no evidence that anyone has abused you.

If you *have* evidence of this, you should not provide it here (e.g., in the comments). Instead, you should raise a moderator flag to report it—see below.

> I received lot of negative reviews.

What do you mean by this? None of your recent questions have had *any* reviews at all. (One, the very latest one, has now entered the [Reopen review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen), but it hasn't had anyone review it yet.)

> I closed one of the questions, but it was reopened and still receive a lot of dovnvotes.

I really have no idea what you're talking about. You have not closed any of your questions. In fact, it is not *possible* for you to single-handedly close one of your questions without any other users being involved. Also, none of your recently-closed questions has ever been reopened.

> In my opinion the question is very good quality and meet all stack overflow guidelines.

Great! Then you don't need to do anything else.

Downvotes, like upvotes, are just the expression of someone's opinion. Each user has the privilege of casting one vote per post, based on their own subjective assessment of the post's quality, suitability, clarity, usefulness, interestingness, and a variety of other individual factors. A post's score serves as feedback to both the post's author and (mainly) future viewers. It represents the aggregate assessment of the community at large regarding the quality of that post. If you receive downvotes, but think your post is high quality, then it is reasonable to ignore the feedback provided by the downvotes. There is no need to take any action.

> I would like to remove it.

We do not allow users to delete questions that have been answered, as this is detrimental to our goal of building a knowledge base. As the system message tells you when you attempt to do this, deleting the question would also hide the associated answer(s), which people took time to write and may prove useful to future viewers. This is the whole goal/philosophy of Stack Exchange. We would only allow users to delete their own questions under *exceptional* circumstances. I see nothing exceptional here, just you making up random accusations because you received some downvotes...

See also: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

> I will report that abusing user to moderator, but will do it later, not now

Sure, yes; if you feel someone is abusing you, then raising a moderator flag on one of your posts (preferably one where the abuse happened) and reporting it would be the appropriate thing to do. One or more of the moderators will look into it and decide how to handle the situation. Make sure that you present *actual evidence* in your moderator flag (the "in need of moderator intervention" flag option will give you a free-form textbox that you can type into); otherwise, your flag will be summarily declined.

See also: [How do I report harassment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/harassment)

Comment: "*I closed one of the questions*" I think OP was referring to them deleting their meta question before 3 other people voted undelete it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I will read it carefully and use it of course with an evidence. I have an account here since 10 years, and this is the first time ever when I got a lot harassment (downvotes, a lot of fixes, closing questions, threatening me that my account will be deleted, appealing to my reputation) mostly from one specific user. Thank you one more time. Your answer is very helpful. However I dont understand why the question you answered gets downvoted.

Comment: Who has threatened your account will be deleted?

Comment: Downvotes, edits, and closing questions **are not harassments!**. These are just normal everyday actions on the site. It's the same as upvotes or reopening closed questions are not harassment. Please do not take things so personally.

Comment: Ok, so lets allow everyone to downvote my last 3 questions. No problem... Who has threatened me? I was for example warned like this: `high-rep users who believe they can be exempted from the rules will get very short shrift.` I do not think like this I can do anything, but it is ok? Also I cannot find similar comments now‍♂️ Have no idea whether they have been deleted by the user or it was just my imagination (I hope not).

Comment: I mean... some random person saying something wrong on the internet... isn't really that surprising, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ When you bring attention to yourself via posting on meta, some people *do* look to the users recent questions to see if there's some kind of trend with regard to question quality that can be leading to you receiving more downvotes. People *shouldn't* be also voting on posts found in that way, but there's nothing stopping users from doing so.

Comment: @KevinB you are right, it is quite positive;)

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk at 20K+ reputation site gave you all powers available to non-moderator users. It is *not* a harassment to remind you (or anyone at that level) that site put huge amount of trust in you and expect you to set an example of how to one is expected to behave/post/edit/moderate.  It is extremely frustrating to see "trusted" users openly flouting the rules (missing MRE, images instead of code, claiming "my post is f**ing clear" and the like). While it is possible to ChatGPT such comment to make it nicer it is not really possible to soften the message: trusted users == higher bar.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thank you. You are right. I try to improve everything and do my best in next questions and answers;)