# Victim of serial up voting

Tags: support, serial-voting

Yesterday, I got up voted for three old questions and answers (exactly three). One of the answers I got up voted for does not even deserve to get up voted. So I'm suspecting that I'm being a victim of serial up voting.

Two months ago Stack Overflow administration subtracted my reputation by 300 points because a friend of mine was up voting all my accepted answers. Since then I have warned my friends to stay away so they cannot bias the process of helping others.

I sent Facebook messages to all my friends asking them were they the ones behind yesterday's up votes but they all denied doing such thing.

What can I do in such situation?

Comment: just wait and let the system do it's thing. Looks like you received 6 total upvotes in that period, so it'l likely get caught and reversed.

Comment: @KevinB Yes three on three answers and three on three questions. How long it usually takes the system to do its thing?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes/252271#252271 3am UTC apparently

Comment: cross-site reference as well: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me

Comment: "victim ... upvote" ... Proposed alternate title: "What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge upvotes?"

Comment: I sometimes get 2 upvotes on old questions, just after helping someone. Surprisingly I didn't flag them :)

Comment: Also you cannot help people you helped to check your profile, look other answers you made, and since they like your style and they learn things which interest them, they upvote. As long as they don't upvote _all_ your answers, of course

Comment: Thank you so much guys, everyone who commented you were a great help.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, It's not just that they shouldn't vote on *all*, it's that the real issue is the votes should be on the *actual content* of the post, not the user. If some person goes through several/multiple of another user's posts, one-by-one, and reads and evaluates the content of each one, in isolation of who wrote it, and then votes their conscience based on that content, then those are valid votes. Doing that [is difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260843/3773011), but if you can, it is legit to do so. ([additional meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335442/3773011))

Comment: funny, I just got serial downvoting on my questions... Just when I thought I improved when giving feedback.. Or it's just jealous bastards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, I wouldn't worry about it. If the system automatically invalidates these votes, great. If not, it's probably not worth bringing to the attention of moderators or SE staff. I'd just shrug and move on.

If you're being attacked with a series of downvotes, we'll step in, but even then three votes might not be enough to establish a clear pattern.

For a series of upvotes, this generally will only warrant moderator intervention if we see obvious coordination between the accounts. There are times when people try to troll others with repeated streams of serial upvotes, but those incidents are pretty rare. Most of the time, it's pretty clear when the serial upvotes are coming from someone who is a fan of someone's work, has a misplaced desire to pay someone back for help they received, or the two people just naturally interact in a particular tag.

Like you said, we had pretty clear indications that the first round of voting was unnaturally coordinated, so those votes were manually invalidated. This time, I'm not seeing any such coordination, so there's nothing more for us to do here.