# Is asking for "sample code" on / off topic; or "depends"?

Tags: discussion, scope

I claimed "off-topic" on [Read and write a file in Mainframes from omvs region using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399702/read-and-write-a-file-in-mainframes-from-omvs-region-using-java); another user respectfully disagrees.

Questions:

- this specific question ... on/off topic?
- is there a general answer to "off-topic-ness" for "here problem; somebody got sample code for that?" questions?

Comment: Maybe reword the question? I mean "maybe"?

Comment: Maybe I don't get the pun. I am not a pundit regarding word games.

Comment: Sometimes the problem is about [wording](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341987/792066), or asking the right question. In those cases, editing the question may be a solution.

Comment: Sometimes the problem is about wording, sometimes you need to read minds. But in most case, it's op 1rst post and he will never come back. Some are still reading the tuto.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The question itself isn't great but nor is the current chosen close reason.

I have no doubt that question needs to be closed as we need the OP to expand on their specific issue and narrow their question to that. I can't make out if they are struggling with running Java, running Java from a client, using `com.ibm.jzos.ZFile`, if they have either compile-time, runtime, syntax or functional errors.

Looking at that question these would be my preferred order of closing that question:

- Unclear what you're asking
  the good part of this close notice is that it contains a link to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which can help the OP on how to improve their question
- Too broad
  because I can't make out where I would need start explaining how to resolve the issue at hand as I'm unsure at which knowledge level the OP is.
- why isn't this code working?
  would work if I feel generous and assume the OP already has some code but forgot to include it. The close notice will point to [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) helping the OP in providing just enough code to repro their issue.
- Off-site resource
  I think this is not as blatantly asking for an off-site-resource (YMMV) as many others so this would be my last preferred close reason. The OP would probably be more confused by this and wouldn't know how to improve their question.

Comment: The question explicitly asks for _"Is there any sample code available for doing this?"_, that is - to me - asking for an offsite resource. It is just an alternative phrasing for asking for a tutorial or a link to documentation, examples, etc.

Answer (score 10):

The irony here is that such questions should be warmly welcomed on Stack Overflow, *if properly worded and not duplicated*. A code example for a generalized task, such as "How to make an AJAX call" or "How to select rows from a database based on a certain condition" would make an extremely useful contribution, given an answer indeed provides a solid state-of-art example.

But not on Stack Overflow.

There are two kinds of people in the world: ones who read answers on Stack Overflow and ones who write questions. **In theory**, the second is imagined to be used as a source of answers for the first. **In practice**, however, they need different answers completely: ones who ask need an answer for a too localized question, while ones who read need rather a generalized answer (which makes the question too broad). *Both considered off topic on Stack Overflow.*

To make it worse

- most of time the OP don't ask "how to do something". If you open the question, it turns out that they actually know how to perform the task in general, and have the code all right. While asking **how fix an error in their particular implementation**. Which makes any answer deliberately useless for anyone else (ok, with few exceptions of highly common mistakes).
- nobody ever cares for a generalized solution: answers are getting into minute details of the question, absolutely pointless for anyone else.

So, to answer your question:

In a better world, a question asking for a sample code, given it's properly worded and not duplicated, should be the main goal of this site.

In reality, such questions either gets closed or turn into a live debugging orgy, which is directly prohibited by the rules, but highly appreciated by all participants and thus cannot be extinguished.

In the future, if the authorities will succeed with their plans, there will be two Stack Overflow sites:

- The **main** Documentation site where people are coming from Google for the solutions
- The **supplementary** *forum-like* Stack Overflow with "fix my code" questions finally *legalized*.

This will essentially fix the current awkward status-quo, and let ones who search to have good answers; while letting ones who prefer live chattering to enjoy it unrestrained. Of course if the authorities will have the guts and vision to accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. But if gaining reputation would be made much easier by allowing those "help me fixing my code things"; what is they joy of gaining reputation then?

Comment: in my opinion, making people having fun gaining reputation is the last thing you would choose if you need the quality content.

Comment: `live debugging orgy` seems to be exactly what a lot of people need coming here

Comment: Two things: A) that *future plans*, where can one find more infos about that? B) what I meant is: very often it is *hard work* to gain reputation on the main SO (maybe not so on when you are mainly working with tags that easily give hundreds or thousands of views) ... so the "fun" or better "motivational" part is to know: "this is something special that not too many people achieve". If there would be a "systematic" change; that would result in "many more" people getting to 5, 6 digit rep counts and elite, legendary badges ... at least for me; I would probably lose interest "working" here ...

Answer (score 7):

As it stands actually, this specific question is a "Give me the code" question which doesn't show an attempt, nor a description on research done and how they didn't fit or why the OP didn't understood the results from research. Those kind of question can fit in a variety of close reasons (unclear/too broad/er question tutorial, depending on each case).

I also had voted to close, and five people agree with you; even the second comment author agree the question as it stands is not fit for Stack Overflow.

---

For the generic on-topic/off-topic subject, asking for code is what all questions are about, so I'd say it's on-topic.

The way it should be asked is described on the help/how-to-ask page and there's some discussions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342060/fixing-the-no-sample-input-no-expected-output-and-show-us-your-code-proble) on meta about this.

And it boils down more or less to *[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3627607)*.

Comment: [Questions are not off topic solely because they don't contain code, nor because they are asking for code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284298/is-it-okay-to-ask-a-new-question-about-an-answer). They can be off topic for any number of other reasons as rene pointed out, but not because of the reasoning you present here.

Comment: @TinyGiant My point was not about code or no code, more about lack of research and description of what is failing, => too broad or Unclear reasons. I'm unsure of what you find my reasoning to be in fact. As I don't feel I present no code or asking for code being a reason on itself.

Comment: @TinyGiant Specially when I say " asking for code is what all question are about, so I'd say it's on-topic." I feel I'm on the same line... So I really don't get your point. (And I took some time to read your link again, and I don't see how it is related)

Comment: Your first sentence reads as implying that questions asking for code are off-topic. Unless you're just saying the question asks for code, in which case the first sentence would be irrelevant

Comment: @TinyGiant I quoted the term as a classification one, and the second sentence is not on a separated paragraph to explain it/why it's bad on this form. Would it be better if worded "Gimme the CodeZ" (or any other variation) as seen usually on meta to avoid confusion ?

Comment: I see what you're saying now. Personally I think everything before _"how they didn't fit"_ is irrelevant.

Comment: @TinyGiant Would make not much sense then (as the rest of the sentence would not relate to anything). As the usage of "give me the code" appears quite often for this kind of question, I feel OK using it along with it's "meta meaning" (I've no better idea to express this). If you have an idea to word this in a better way, feel free to edit.

Comment: I personally hate the use of that name for such questions because it implies such questions are off-topic. The fact that a question asks for code or does not show research effort is entirely irrelevant when evaluation questions for closure. I would have phrased the first sentence as _"The question does not contain enough detail to answer, or the answer required would be too broad for this format."_

Comment: @TinyGiant Well, when the lack of research ends up that the best answer is to link to a tutorial, .... then it's off-topic, what most of this kind of question are. The question concerned is exactly that, [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.zsecurity.api.80.doc/com.ibm.jzos/com/ibm/jzos/ZFile.html#ZFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) would answer the "Is there any sample code available for doing this" (quoted from the question)

Comment: If the best answer is a link to a tutorial that means the question is too broad. That is not because the question doesn't show research but because the question is too broad. And I don't see _any evidence whatsoever_ supporting the claim that most questions that ask for code are off-topic or are too broad. Asking for sample code does not imply that the sample code should exist elsewhere, it's just asking for an example of how to do a thing. If the thing being asked for is too broad, it's too broad. Many of my favorite questions ask how to do a thing without providing an example or research.

Comment: Well, first part of my answer concern the question linked in the meta question. It is not a global rule, my general position is in the second part of the answer. I think we have a misunderstanding on this point in fact.