# Is asking a question about a question okay?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

In this question, the author is asking about another question:

[Kendo UI Issue with latest MSCRM Online version 9.0.2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52205616)

In that case, it looks like they were trying to reply, so I initially voted to close until edits were made.

But, as a general principle, is asking a question about a question okay?

Comment: Related: [Is it okay to ask a new question about an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284298/4639281)

Comment: Did I get a downvote because my question about a question is a question about a question?

Comment: You can ask a question about a question but you should NEVER ask a question about asking a question.  You should just ask your question and then question whether or not the question was questioned and if so why the questioner questioned it.

Comment: @billynoah Are you serious in the first part of your comment ("you should NEVER ask a question about asking a question") or are you joking throughout your whole comment? Because I see many people asking on meta about "should I ask this question", like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373756/can-i-post-a-question-about-unexplainable-javascript-operator-performance?cb=1

Comment: @Sweeper - the whole comment is just a silly joke

Comment: We even have the [meta-tag:specific-question] meta tag, so (for meta) the answer is a clear Yes!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But, as a general principle; is asking a question about a question okay?

Of course it is!

What other options do you have if you feel a question that is close to the problems you have but don't exactly understand what the difference is between their context and yours.

In this specific case they could maybe lift some more context from that question but I don't think it warrants a close vote. An edit, sure. (which I just did).

Answer (score 4):

One of my highest voted [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16846573/1324033) is about another question I had.

It doesn't matter what prompts the question, all that matters is that it is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and follows the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

It usually depends on the actual question.

Answers have a requirement to be an actual answer, and the same goes for questions: they need to be actual questions. If it should be an edit, a comment, or a compliment, then you should absolutely close it and probably also delete it after the OP puts it in the right place.

On the other hand, there's absolutely nothing wrong with legitimate follow-up questions. Try this as a general rule: if it were a comment, would it be on the question, or one of its answers?

Comment: How can a question about a previous question posted as a new question be flagged as not an answer? Questions are expected to not be answers... generally.

Comment: @TinyGiant hang on, let me clarify that.

Comment: @TinyGiant is this good?